# Converting this algorithm in TCL

Tags: tcl

I need help in converting this algorithm into tcl for my work, I am not so good in tcl language.

```
Inputs: STA−1, STA−2, STA−3, ..., STA−n
//requests from various stations for channel access
Shared Variables:
  for every i, 1 ≤ i ≤ n
    counter[i] ∈ { / 0, 1, 2,..., N}, initially 0, updated by stations
  Sequence Number, K ∈ { / 0, 1, 2,..., N}, initially 0, will be set to a positive integer
Procedure:
  //Initialization
  Set sequence number K = m; //based on the action selected
  for (i = 1 to n)
    counter[i] = 0;
  for (i = 1 to n)
  {
    while (channel access[i])
      if (counter[i]! = K)
      {
        if (channel == idle)
        {
          if (counter[i]<min(counter[i+1], counter[i+2], ..., counter[i + n]))
            access channel;
          else
            defer access;
        }
        counter[i]+ +;
      }
      else 
        defer access;
  }
```

This is for CPS devices to access internet using a WSN in between..basic network is done but need help with adding this algo to it..
Can someone help me code that algo in tcl?

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear enough.
For syntax, I'd recommend referring TCL online help.

Some quick snippets:

```
# Inputs: STA−1, STA−2, STA−3, ..., STA−n
set stations [list "STA−1" "STA−2" "STA−3"]

# Shared Variables:
# for every i, 1 ≤ i ≤ n
# counter[i] ∈ { / 0, 1, 2,..., N}, initially 0, updated by stations

array set counter {}
set n 10
set i 0
while {$i < $n} {
    set counter($i) 0
    incr i
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The core of your method is converted to this, assuming that `counter` is converted to an (associative) array, and that channel identifiers are stored in the `channel` array:

```
variable K 0

for {set i 1} {$i <= $n} {incr i} {
    set counter($i) 0
}

for {set i 1} {$i <= $n} {incr i} {
    while {[channelAccess $channel($i)]} {
        if {$counter($i) != $K} {
            if {[channelIdle $channel($i)]} {
                set minimum [getMinimum [expr {$i + 1}] [expr {$i + $n}]]
                if {$counter($i) < $minimum} {
                    accessChannel $channel($i)
                } else {
                    deferAccess $channel($i)
                }
            }
            incr counter($i)
        } else {
            deferAccess $channel($i)
        }
    }
}
```

You'll also need this procedure:

```
proc getMinimum {from to} {
    upvar 1 counter counter
    set minVal $counter($from)
    for {set i $from} {$i <= $to} {incr i} {
        set minVal [expr {min($minVal, $counter($i))}]
    }
    return $minVal
}
```

And you'll need to define `channelAccess`, `channelIdle`, `accessChannel` and `deferAccess`; they're things that your algorithm doesn't specify. There's also nothing to say what various variable are actually updated by. But that's the *algorithm* converted.

Note the patterns for using `for`; those are idiomatic Tcl for this sort of thing. Also note the brace positioning; your life will be easiest in Tcl if you use that style.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This algorithm can be written in .tcl file or should be specified in aodv.h and aodv.cc..if so how to call this algorithm from aodv.h from .tcl? and where should I define ChannelAccess and all other classes ?